# How can I query a ParseObject collection asynchronously in my ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform, parse-dotnet-sdk

I have tried the following. Currently, I'm just trying to read the collection of objects queried in the console. According to the guide, asynchronous queries are preferred: http://docs.parseplatform.org/dotnet/guide/#queries

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Task<int> task = HandleMessagesAsync();
            task.Start();

        }

        private async Task<int> HandleMessagesAsync()
        {
            var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Message");
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(results);

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Start may not be called on a promise-style task.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Task` class starts automatically, as per this guide: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/70f82b79-188e-4e91-8f86-b5a9382663fb/problem-with-taskstart?forum=netfxbcl

There is no need to invoke `.Start();`

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Task<int> task = HandleMessagesAsync();
        }

        private async Task<int> HandleMessagesAsync()
        {
            var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Message");
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
            var count = await query.CountAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine("# Message: " + count);

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I used `Debug.WriteLine("# Message: " + count);` to make sure that the correct number of Message objects were queried from my database.

Comment: This is not good async code.  You need to use async/await throughout the call.  Otherwise you will randomly have task deadlocks.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm not sure where else I'd use ``await`` in the above code... Can you provide an alternative?

Comment: Fundamentally if you're using MVC you shouldn't be passing a class that makes external calls to itself to a view/page.  If you need to create an object and it has external dependencies to become a valid object during construction, I wouldn't use a constructor, I'd use the factory method.  The factory method can be made async.